# How would I get my js Discord bot to post an embed to a public channel on the event on a private channel receiving a message?

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm new to this and I feel like I've hit a wall!

I have a webhook setup so any new sales for a product get posted to a private channel for an admin to action, I have just created a 'sales train' bot that will simply post a nice embed when i run the !sale command in general chat but would prefer if it posted this automatically everytime a new sales order came through the private channel via the webhook.

Here's my code atm

```
client.on('message', message => {
if (message.content === '!sale') {  

  message.delete()

  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(16763136)
        .setThumbnail('https://thumbnnailURL')
        .setDescription("*Another customer has just signed up for 1 month!*\n      \n **FOMO? Head to <#pricingchannelID> to find out more!**")
        .setTitle(`  SALE TRAIN COMING THROUGH!`)

    message.channel.send(embed);
});
```

Is it possible to add something where it can watch the private channel ID for a message then post this embed to the public channel ID when it's triggered? Any help is appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: step one would be to realize javascript and java aren't the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sussed it!

```
    client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.channel.id === 'CHANNEL ID THE WEBHOOK/MESSAGE IS BEING SENT TO') {  

const channel = client.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL ID THE EMBED GETS SENT TO")

      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(x)
            .setThumbnail('x')
            .setDescription("x")
            .setTitle(`x`)
    
        channel.send(embed);
    }
```